# Wordpress Subfolder move to ROOT

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, directory, root

to start it all off :

What I want to achieve is just a simple removal of the /folder name after my website.com URL
and have all my links and Wordpress login just under website.com/wp-login.php.
But have been habinf lots and lots of touble trying to overcome this and looking through other posts and trying all I can , just to wind back up to square one.

1.) I did a restore function of a test site on my main site (website.com) which is in folder /site.

2.) After the successful restore using a plugin (WP Clone), My site at website.com works. But once I click on other links and pages , they go to website.com/site.

3.) I have tried

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress , 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

to no avail. They either end up screwing my themes up, screw my HTTPS up , or screw up my wp-login and keep redirecting to unkown places and keep me from logging in to wp-dashboard.

If there is anyone who understands what Im doing wrong , or missed something out, please do help me.. I really have to fix this problem and apprecaite your help very very much

Comment: Are the URLs pointing to the wrong address e.g. /site/ - so that when you click them, they go to that by default?

Comment: For now, I have returned them to default . the site address URL in settings have /site , so now all my permalinks have a /site in them.
If I remove the /site and change the .htaccess file. Problems occur